# If bound on induced $\mathcal{L}_2$ gain is given, then can we give upper bound on induced $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ gain?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure, control-theory

Given $u(t) \in \mathcal{L}_2$ and $y(t) \in \mathcal{L}_2$, let the induced gain is given by $\gamma$ as shown below

$$ \lVert z \rVert_2 \leq \gamma \lVert u \rVert_2 $$

similarly, for $u(t) \in \mathcal{L}_\infty$ and $y(t) \in \mathcal{L}_\infty$, let the induced gain is given by $\beta$ as shown below

$$ \lVert z \rVert_\infty \leq \beta \lVert u \rVert_\infty $$

> The question that I want to ask is can we give upper bound on $\beta$ in terms of $\gamma$?

Comment: Please give some context: What is $\mathcal L_p$, in particular what is the domain of the functions? Is it $\mathbb R$? What is $z$, do you mean $y$? Do you mean that $\gamma=\|z\|_2/\|u\|_2$ for $\|u\|_2>0$? Thanks!

Comment: Please review the answers to your previous questions before moving on to new ones. Please also improve your post by providing all the necessary details.

Comment: @Matija Here $u(t)$ is a signal and $\mathcal{L}_2$ is the 2 norm for signal $u(t)$. I meant $\gamma$ is $\mathcal{H}_{\infty}$ norm, similarly $\beta$ is the $\mathcal{L}_1$ norm.

Comment: @KBS I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience, I have reviewed the previous question, also I am looking for some other answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I guess you will need to provide more context here. There are ways to calculate the different gains and trying to compute one (or an upper-bound) from another is not necessarily a good strategy as it will be very conservative.

Comment: @KBS I agree with you, thanks for the comment.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, "$\mathcal L_2$ is the $2$-norm for signal $u(t)$" translates to $\mathcal L_2=\|u\|_2$, meaning that $\mathcal L_2$ is a number, which is contradicts $u(t)\in\mathcal L_2$, implying that $\mathcal L_2$ is a set. Sorry for the annoying questions, I honestly try to understand what you are trying to convey.

Comment: I meant to say that $u(t)$ is a signal and it belongs to $\mathcal{L}_2$ space ($\mathcal{L}_2$ space is the space of square integrable functions), and yes $\lVert u \rVert_2$ is the $\mathcal{L}_2$ norm of $u$, which is a number. Please correct me if I am mistaking.

Comment: It holds $\beta \le \gamma$.

Comment: @Arastas Can you please give justifications ? or some reference

Comment: Given the tags, I assume you consider a SISO LTI system, where $u$ is an input signal, and $z$ is the corresponding output signal under zero initial conditions. Is that true?

Comment: It is true that $\gamma \leq \beta$, however even for SISO LTI system, I am not sure how the converse inequality is true.

Comment: As $y(s) = \int_0^t h(t-s)u(s)ds$, it follows that $\|y\|_\infty \le \int_0^\infty |h(t-s)|ds\|u\|_\infty$.